# Data type and Value type

Tags: javascript

i'm a newbie in Javascript. (3 weeks into it). I'm trying to get a hang of the basics. So straight to my question: "3" === 3 returns false. "Because they are not the same **data type** **or** **value**." I understand the difference in the data types since "3" is a string and 3 is a number. The value part of it seems lost on me. Shouldn't it be false because of only the difference in data type and not value? I assumed "value" means 3. Clarification on this will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: yep, that's why it says "**or** value"

Comment: if you want to return `true` then use double equal `"3" == 3` which will not check data type.

Comment: If it's not the same *type*, `===` is always `false`. If it's the same *type* but a different *value*, it's also `false`.

Comment: If they are different data types, then the value is *always* different, from a technical perspective.

Comment: `2 === 3` also returns `false`, but now because of a difference in value not in type

Comment: The triple = symbols also tests the data type as well as the values. In your example,  the string 3 does not equal the number 3.

Comment: @Kos, the "or" would have been irrelevant then. It should just say "because of a difference in data type". @ Thomas My concern is does "value" mean the actual number 3 itself or "number" value as a data type? Because "Eloquent Javascript" book refers to data types as value types too. So you can see why i'm confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TL;DR: To humans, it looks like `3` and `"3"` have the same value, but to a computer, they look very different.

Variables with different data types can't have the same value, as their data is stored differently. Strings store each letter individually (so a longer string will require more storage space), whereas a number always takes up the same amount of space (so a larger number will not require more storage than a small number).

Another way to think of it is this: `3` is the number 3. `"3"` contains the letter 3. Letters are stored differently than numbers, so even though they look the same to you, `3` and `"3"` look very different to a computer.

`3` the number, in binary, might look like this:

01000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

whereas `"3"` the letter looks like this:

00000000 00110011

Answer (score 0):

**== Operators(Equality)**

The equality operator converts the **operands** if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Example of **== Operator**

```
0    == false      // true
0    == null       // false
```

**Identity / strict equality (===)**

The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal with **no type conversion**.

Example of **=== Operator**

`3 === 3   // true`
 `3 === '3' // false`

Tou can visit this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) to found out more JavaScript operators.

Comment: This doesn't address his question. He's asking why `3 === "3"` fails for both type and value rather than just type.

Comment: 3 is  **integer** and "3" is **string**.. using === strict equality so it should  both,  `3 === 3` **integer**  or `"3" === "3"` a **string**.

Comment: @EKW I believe you have answered my question. I assumed how i interpreted 3 and "3" is the same way a computer does. Thanks and thanks to the rest as well.

Comment: Yes, but OP is not asking why it returns false. OP is saying that he thinks `3 === "3"` returns false because, although (according to OP) the values are the same, the data types are different. OP's textbook is saying that the values AND the data types are different.

Comment: @JSpecs if I answered your question, please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: One last question guys. Is value type and data type interchangeable? As i mentioned by book explains "There are 6 types of values in Javascript....". Though i just refer to them as data types.

Comment: @EKW like i said also 3 is **integer** and that is data type while "3" is  **string** in which on his example of `3==="3" where "3" is his **value**..

Answer (score 0):

You should read it as

> two operands of '===' are **not equal** if they are **not the same data type or value**

or more simply to understand:

> A strict comparison (e.g., ===) is only **true** if the operands are of the **same type and the contents match.**

Source: [Comparison operators](https://web.archive.org/web/20171019084443/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. OP is saying that he thinks 3 === "3" returns false because, although (according to OP) the values are the same, the data types are different. OP's textbook is saying that the values AND the data types are different.

Comment: @EKW his question is about logic of phrase which he took too literal for given example

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has both strict and type-converting equality comparison. For strict equality the objects being compared must have the same type and:

Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions.

Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.

Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are false.

Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.

Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===). [I.e. (Null==Undefined) is true but (Null===Undefined) is false]

For better understanding look below code

```
0 == false   // true
0 === false  // false, because they are of a different type
1 == "1"     // true, automatic type conversion for value only
1 === "1"    // false, because they are of a different type
null == undefined // true
null === undefined // false
'0' == false // true
'0' === false // false
```